# Save Socket Connections

Tags: java, sockets

So i am about to create an IRC like Chat Proramm.
Did all the GUI stuff for the client application.

Now my problem is that I want to have multiple user connecting to one server. that server has a lot of chat rooms and each room has a list of user who are currently in there.

How can i create a Methode User.message(string message). where do i store the socket? Can i just store a ClientConnection, which is a runnable, in my User Class?

```
public class ClientConnection implements Runnable {
    private final Socket CLIENT;
    private String sendLine;
    private String nextLine;

    private BufferedReader in;
    private PrintWriter out;
    public ClientConnection(Socket s){
        CLIENT = s;

        try{
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(CLIENT.getInputStream()));
            out = new PrintWriter(CLIENT.getOutputStream(), false);
        }catch(IOException IOEx){
            IOEx.printStackTrace();
        }

        sendLine = "DATE";
    }

    public void run(){
        try{

            while(true){

                if((nextLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println(nextLine);
                }

                if(sendLine != null){
                    out.println(sendLine);
                    sendLine = null;
                }
            }

        }catch(SocketException SOEx){
                System.out.println("Client Connection Closed");
                return;
        }catch(IOException IOEx){
            IOEx.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void sendMessage(String m){
        this.sendLine = m;
    }
```

Comment: Your read loop doesn't make sense. If `readLine()` returns null you must stop reading, and probably close the socket.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a mediator to store all active users (`ClientConnection` -s). This messenger is used in order to send a group message to consumers.
Use the constructor in `ClientConnection` to register it in the mediator.

Comment: "must use a mediator" - I did not realise that this is the **only** possible implementation of chat engine???

Comment: this is great thank you, i really didnt know what to search for.